# Database unit test bound to implementation detail

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have a simple PHP-Class that wraps the access to the database to retrieve a user and want to unit-test it. I currently have the following code:

The class to test:

```
class UserTable {

    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(\Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function getUserWithId($id) {
        return $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id])->current();
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
class UserTableTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testGetUserWithIdReturnsCorrectUser() {
        $user = new User();

        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->initialize([$user]);

        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('\Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', ['select'], [], '', false);
        $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())->method('select')->with(['id' => 1])->willReturn($resultSet);

        $userTable = new UserTable($mockTableGateway);

        $this->assertEquals($user, $userTable->getUserWithId(1));
    }
}
```

However, now the unit test would fails if I later decided to change the way I use the table gateway (e.g. use `select(['id = ?' => $id]`).  This binds the unit test to an implementation detail of `getUserWithId($id)` which should be avoided.

What would be best practice to prevent the unit test from depending on an implementation detail? Is it worth the effort to set up an actual testing database that the unit test can run against (which will also slow down the execution of the test dramatically) or is there a better way to mock the table gateway?

Comment: You could create your own gateway object, that you always use and then these table tests only ever interface with one gateway, but should implementation change you only change it in your custom gateway, instead of everywhere that uses that zend table gateway

Comment: That's what my UsersTable was actually designed to do. To encapsulate the Zend TableGateway one step further and provide an interface for the rest of the application. So, you're suggesting to add another level of abstraction that simply wraps the TableGateway on its own, contains no logic and does not have to be tested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not mock code that you don't own!* For classes that use database, you have to write integration tests. The good things is that this will force you to separate the DB access from other logic.

*This is actual advice from the "Growing object-oriented software, guided by tests" book, backed up by my own experience with writing tests for code that uses Doctrine's Entity Manager