# Mocking DB/SQL fat free framework (F3) phpunit

Tags: phpunit, fat-free-framework

I am trying to write a test for a function which returns false or object.

```
class Environment {


    protected $db , $env, $envMapper= "";

    public function __construct($dbConnection) {
        $this->db = $dbConnection;
        $this->setMapper($this->db);
    }


    public function setMapper($db){
        $this->envMapper=new DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db,'environment');
    }

    public function save($envName) {
        $this->envMapper->name = $envName;
        return $this->envMapper->save();
    }

    /**
     * @param $envId
     */
    public function get($envId) {

    }

    /***
     * @param $envName
     */
    public function getByName($envName) {

    }
}
```

Tests:

```
class EnvironmentTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $db = "";


    public function setup()
    {
        $this->db = $this->getMockBuilder('SqlHelper')
            ->setMethods(array('connect'))
            ->getMock();
    }


    public function testSave() {
        $object = new StdClass();
        $env = new Environment($this->db);
        $this->assertEquals($object, $env->save('Test'));
    }
}
```

I am not sure how should I change so that it would be testable, it always return

> EnvironmentTest::testSave
>   PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: You cannot serialize or
>   unserialize PDO instances

Comment: You cannot serialize the DB object, that's what the error message said. I don't see where you or maybe PHPunit does this, but it's clearly a PDO limitation.

Comment: I think the following link should help you: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1171

Comment: You should not use a mock in this test, as you effectively won't test anything. Refer [to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27187532/797303)

Comment: Yes I agree to you but right now it not effective to test, however is there something like dependancy injection in F3, where before routing to the method I can pass the constructor values with the PDO object or mapper object. Right now I am not able to find any other option than not to test it .